# How Does Replacing Repeated Code With a Function Affect Performance in an Interpreted Language Such as Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets say I wrote a large section of code and copied it ten times. How would performance (CPU usage, ram usage, running time) change if I were to make the code a function and call it 10 times?

Comment: The only way to know is to benchmark it yourself, because the code itself could change the results.  Fortunately Python has the `timeit` module to make benchmarking easy.

Comment: One of the things I love about Python is how easy it is to break a small piece of code off and put it in its own function.  Being able to have multiple return values makes it painless.  Function parameters don't get copied either so there's not the performance penalty you might find in other languages.